# Regex for twitter hastags not linking properly?

Tags: php, regex, twitter

I have a basic regex function that converts the hastags into links but the problem I have is that it only converts the actual word into a link and leaves the # alone. I want the # to be part of the link... inside the a tag.

What it produces:

```
#<a href="">hastag</a>
```

What I want:

```
<a href="">#hastag</a>
```

My php code:

```
public function link_hashtags($text)
{
    $text = preg_replace('/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/', '\1#<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23\2">\2</a>', $text);
    return $text;

}
```

It does pass the word correctly as I dont want the hashtag passed to the url, any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried putting the # symbol into the a tag but then it produces double the hashtags.. which isnt what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `#` symbol within the `<a>` tag as you did, but also take out the one preceding the tag...

Comment: Yes thank you, that worked, I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match words that are prepended with a hash tag, you could use the following regex:

```
/#([^\s]+)/

<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23\1">#\1</a>
```

Use a back reference of \1 inside the anchor.

Comment: In his case this wouldn't work because the backreference would include the ``#`` which isn't valid for the ``href`` part...

Comment: Move the hash tag outside the parenthesis then.

Comment: See edit. Put them in seperate capturing groups, and reference them as above.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean by separate capturing groups.

Comment: The parenthesis designate a capturing group, anything inside them can be back referenced. In your own example you have used back references...